# Redirecting to new domain page without changing the old domain name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have two different domains olddomain.com and newdomain.com .All working pages are in olddomain only. Only one page in new domain So,when they click on newdomain/subpageurl content should display from newdomain/subpage but url should be olddomain.com/subpage

newdomain.com/subpage1 -->olddomain.com/subpage1

But URL should be like olddomain.com/subpage1

I tried this..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} olddomain.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This is confusing, in my eyes you contradict yourself here: if there is only one "page" in newdomain, then how can someone "click on newdomain/subpageurl"? Or is there really a link in olddomain that points to newdomain? _Why?_

Comment: Also: if that "page" on newdomain actually contains multiple pages, objects, whatever (only then it makes sense to talk about newdomain.com/subpage and newdomain.com/subpage1), then how should links in there know about olddomain?

Comment: Please invest some time into revising this question. Maybe add a list of example URL, adding what each URL should actually load (from which domain) and what URL should be displayed. Also add some examples for existing links, how they are coded.

Comment: @arkascha I'm working in olddomain.com. There is one menu option if they click on that menu that should open newdomain.com page. Here, requirement is if the user clicks on menu option it should open newdomain.com/menuoption but in URL the domain name should be olddomain.com. ex: clicks on linnk newdomain.com/subpage  ... URL be like olddomain.com/subpage

Comment: OK, that is a bit more precise. I think in my answer below I made the correct assumptions. For future questions: please do not add additional details or explanations as a comment to the question. Edit the question itself instead. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @arkascha , I have tried that but it was throwing an Internal server error while accessing the https website.

Answer (score 0):

First, You have to put your new domain page file into the old domain. make a sub folder in your old domain root folder. then upload your file into the sub folder. Like
olddomain.com/subfolder/files

Comment: It is  not possible to took whole page code from different domain. So I'm trying to redirect to that page but domain should not change.

Comment: then it is not possible i think.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for a way to implement a transparent proxy inside olddomain forwarding requests to newdomain. As said in the comments to the question you are vague in that.

Two immediate alternatives exist. Both approaches require the proxy module to be loaded into the http server on olddomain.com, obviously. More precisely the proxy *and* the proxy_http module. I assume here that you are using the apache http server to serve olddomain.com ...

---

Using the rewrite module, which is able to use the internal proxy module:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?subpage/?$ https://newdomain.com/subpage [P]
```

The documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p

---

Directly using the proxy module:

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass /subpage https://newdomain.com/subpage
ProxyPassReverse  /subpage https://newdomain.com/subpage
```

Documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass

And yes, it is `ProxyRequests off` and *not* `ProxyRequests on`.

---

Both approaches work for requests targeting olddomain.com (`https://olddomain.com/subpage`). This will *not* work for requests directly targeting newdomain.com. For that you would have to implement an additional external redirection in newdomain.com pointing to olddomain.com. That is a bit tricky however since you have to take care to *not* redirect those requests that came through the proxy on oldcomain.com. Because that would lead to a redirection loop.

Comment: I have tried in this way also. It was showing internal server error while trying to access https website.

Comment: So you will have to check what that internal server actually is. You will find that information in your http server's error log file. Most likely the proxy module is not present in the http server.

Comment: I have already enabled mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http. but it throwing me internal server error 500 while accessing https site.

Comment: As said: you have to take a look into your http server's error log file. No way around that. This file actually is the first place to look at _in all cases_ where you get an internal server error. _You cannot develop a web application without monitoring that log file!_ So what does it reveal what the issue is?

Comment: [Fri Jun 03 10:45:28.941875 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 15400:tid 456] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jun 03 10:45:28.973127 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 15400:tid 456] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jun 03 10:45:28.988753 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 15400:tid 456] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.

Comment: OK, that has nothing to do with this topic here. It just means that you did not setup your SSL certificates correctly, they do not match the http host you are trying to use them for. So either get valid vertificates or you cannot use https, which is absolute standard these days.

Comment: That is not the reason for the status 500, though. There must be more. It is impossible that you get a http status 500 _without_ a corresponding entry in that log file. _Except_ if you turned off logging for that host, which would be a silly thing to do.

Comment: Thankyou @arkascha it is worked. I'm able to access https site through local. But unable to get css and js. Could you please help me.

Comment: I cannot help. All you stated is "Something does not work! Fix it!" I may have a lot of knowledge and experience, but I cannot do magic, sorry. One can only help if you ask precise questions.